# how to swap the time and cpu usage in shell script

Tags: command-line, cpu, sed, time, ps

This is my code here,

```
ps -eo %cpu --sort=-%cpu |head|tail -n+2 | sed "s#^#$(date +%T);#"
```

and the display will be like this:
01:29:29; 1.2

may I know if I want the output like:
1.2;01:29:29

what should I do? PLS give me some advice, tq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^` character anchors to the start of a pattern; to anchor to the end, use `$`. A little care is necessary because you are using "soft" double quotes to allow shell expansion of the date command and `$#` is special to the shell (so must be escaped):

```
ps -eo %cpu --sort=-%cpu |head|tail -n+2 | sed "s#\$#;$(date +%T)#"
```

Alternatively, use the more usual `/` separator for sed:

```
ps -eo %cpu --sort=-%cpu |head|tail -n+2 | sed "s/$/;$(date +%T)/"
```

(since `$/` isn't a special parameter).

Note that you can avoid the need for `tail -n+2` by appending `=` to the `ps -o` specification, and you can avoid the `head` by instructing `sed` to quit after processing 10 lines:

```
ps -eo %cpu= --sort=-%cpu | sed "s/$/;$(date +%T)/;10q"
```

You might also want to take a look at the `ts` command for adding timestamps.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot for helping me solve this question ^^

Comment: But, may I know if I didn't use the command sed, can I get the result too?

Comment: @user1153111 there are several good options for text processing aside from sed - awk, perl, (more recently) miller. For example you could have done `... | awk -v t=$(date +%T) '{print $1";"t} NR==10{exit}'`

Comment: ... or with GNU awk `... | gawk 'BEGIN{ts = strftime("%T",systime()); OFS=";"} {print $1,ts} NR==10{exit}'`

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. I'm still new in Linux, need practice more I guess.